# system not booting after moving /usr directory

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I run a Linux VM on VirtualBox and just made a mistake by moving the contents in /usr to a different partition mounted as /u01. My intention was to free up space for the / file system but realized I should have used cp instead of mv. It's not possible to run any command now. Is there any way I can recover the system?

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , or possibly [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by booting with iso image and mounting the root and restored the contents back to original partition.